# I need help solving a limit, without using l'hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

The limit is $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)$$ 
Please resolve without using l'hôpital's rule, haven't made it that far yet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Have you learned how to find limit *using definition of derivative* yet? if so, you can write it like this:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)}{x} = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x} - \dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\right)= \dfrac{d}{dx}|_{x = 0} \ln(1+x) - \dfrac{d}{dx}|_{x=0} \ln(1-x)=1 - (-1) = 2$

Comment: Is this not L'hopitals?

Comment: @JohnLou.  This is not L'Hopital's Rule.  It's applying the definition of derivative to calculate a limit.

Comment: No, we haven't even started with derivatives yet.

Comment: It seems really similar to L'hopitals, though, as if it were a rudimentary version.

Comment: Completely irrelevant comment: Did anyone ever think L'Hopital's was spelled L'Hospital's before? I did for some reason

Comment: @EricLee L'Hopitals is spelled with an accent circumflex (over the o) in the original French. That usually indicates a missing "s" when converting to English, so it is often spelled both ways. For example, Forest in French is "foret" with an accent over the "s."

Comment: The more you know :D Thank you!

Comment: @JohnLou It is not LHR. It bears a superficial resemblance to it, but it's elementary, and LHR isn't, depending as it does on values of derivatives away from the point in question as well as the Cauchy generalized MVT.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle y=\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$. Then

$$e^y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

$$x=\frac{e^y-1}{e^y+1}$$

As $x\to 0$, $y\to0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y(e^y+1)}{e^y-1}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{e^y-1}\cdot\lim_{y\to0}(e^y+1)=2$$

Comment: How did you evaluate $$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{e^y-1}$$ without L'Hopital?

Comment: That's it! Thank you Kwong.

Comment: He used lhopitals i guess

Comment: @Cerkal No. There are many ways to define the constant $e$. Of course, those definitions are equivalent. We can define $e$ as the number such that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function

Answer (score 1):

There is a very important and useful Taylor series $$\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=2 x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which makes $$\frac 1x\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2+\frac{2 x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: I still remember the time when I first met this series (20 years ago) and used it to calculate $\log 3$ by putting $x=1/2$. Much better than the usual series for $\log(1+x)$ because it converges faster and has all terms positive. +1